# Vegetation indices extraction from RGB images

Tags: ndvi, rgb, vegetation-index

I have been working on the project to classify crops as health or unhealthy. For this task I have taken the open source dataset from the the website https://www.sensefly.com/education/datasets . It has the RGB crop field images and orthomosaic is also available.

I have been reading research paper regarding this and most of the approaches are classification using vegetation indices (NDVI).

I am facing problem in extracting this detail. The method to extract NDVI are being applied on satellite imageries.

How can I extract this data from my aerial images?

Comment: You do know that in order to calculate the NDVI you need data which contains a NIR channel?`

Comment: could you share some details of how can I perform this classification with RGB images.

Comment: yes with NDVI I can't. But are there any other solution to do such classification on aerial images.

Comment: I am not getting it. They are using aerial images generating orthomosaic and extracting the vegetation indices and classifying the crop. I need some guidance related to this so that I get to proper track.

Comment: I did not come across any method till now which can be used to do classification on RGB images. could you please suggest something reagarding this?

Comment: My suggestion is: Get multispectral data and then do the NDVI. I know of no other possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Having only RGB you cannot calculate the NDVI. As stated in the comment, you need as well the NIR (near-infrared) channel (https://gisgeography.com/ndvi-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are Functions for 10 Vegetation Indices in Python, Matlab and R Languages. Hope it useful for you. Link: https://medium.com/@tnmthai/functions-for-10-vegetation-indices-in-python-matlab-and-r-languages-6830161431ac

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fake NDVI (so called "false NDVI") using:

(Green - Red)/(Green + Red - Blue)

Though for me this failed to pick up the more orangey colour of eucalypts, plus it also gave some pretty crazy values in the shadows

What ended up working for me in QGIS is

```
((( "RGB Image@1" + (1.5*"RGB Image@2") - (2.5 * "RGB Image@3") ) / ( "RGB Image@1" + (1.5*"RGB Image@2") + (2.5 * "RGB Image@3"))) + 1) * ((("RGB Image@2" - "RGB Image@3")/("RGB Image@2" + "RGB Image@3")) + 1)
```

Where bands 1, 2 and 3 are red, green and blue

Though this gave false positives for orange roofs and false negatives for wattles, hence why NIR is such an important band for this

[image: Custom Fake NDVI]